# What Version do you have to be on when making a LAN server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What Minecraft Version do you have to be on when making a LAN server?

Comment: The host and the client should be same version, doesn't matter which version.

Answer (score 1):

As @Shayan mentioned, until the host and the client run the same version, it isn't relevant, which version is that.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little more information on how LAN play works on Minecraft,

For LAN play, as long as you have the same version of Minecraft as your friend **it should not matter the version.**

That being said a LAN game is only open to others if they are on the same local network.  In general this means that they have to be connected to the same router/switch that you are connected to. (Without any technical jargon: you need to be connected to the same internet)

If you are on a singleplayer world and you'd like to make it available for others players using your LAN, then you can open the Game Menu and click "Open to LAN."  With this option you can change the gamemode and/or allow cheats.  A second option would be to type  the `/publish` command in the chat, a warning for this method though is you won't be able to adjust game options through the commandline.

By opening your world to LAN you will be assigned an IP that you and your friend can use.  Your friend can connect to the LAN world by *[Scanning for LAN-Worlds](https://appuals.com/fix-lan-not-working-on-minecraft/)* or using the game link that Minecraft provided.

Just as a side note: you both must have separate Minecraft accounts for this to work.